# ¿Cómo hacer una fórmula matemática en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
     
      
      function multiplicar(){
      m1 = document.getElementById("multiplicando").value;
      m2 = document.getElementById("multiplicador").value;
      
      m3 = m2 * 0.01;
      x =  m3 *  parseFloat(m1) ;
      x1 = x-2380000;

      document.getElementById("resultado").value = x1.toLocaleString();
        

      }
      const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      }





      function Sumar() {
          var n1 =1;
          var n2 = document.getElementById('multiplicador').value;
           var suma = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2);
         document.getElementById("multiplicador").value = suma;
          multiplicar();
      }


         function resta() {
              var r1 = 1;
              var r2 = document.getElementById('multiplicador').value;
              var resta = parseInt(r2) - parseInt(r1);
              document.getElementById("multiplicador").value = resta;
             multiplicar();
         }
```

```html
   


 
   <form id="multiplicar">
      <div class="container-block">
  
      <div class="container-input">
        <label>$</label>   <input type="text" name="multiplicando" id="multiplicando"   value="300000000" onChange="multiplicar();"   onkeydown="noPuntoComa( event )"   placeholder="Escribe el valor">
      </div>
     </div>
 

      <div class="container-block">
           
            <div class="accion">
              <input type="button" onclick="resta();" value="-" class="resta">
                        <div class="container-input">
                          <input type="text" name="multiplicador" id="multiplicador" value="3" onChange="multiplicar();" onkeyUp="multiplicar();"   min="0" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                          <label style="    right: 130px;">%</label>
                        </div>
                 <input type="button" onclick="Sumar();" value="+" class="suma">
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-block-resultado">
    
            <div class="container-input">
                <label>$</label>   <input type="text" id="resultado">
              </div>
                </div>

    </form>
```

estoy aprendiendo algo de javascript, quiero hacer una una pequeña operación matematica utilizando miles.

Ejemplo:

300.000.000 * 3% = 900.000

Esto es lo que se le debe mostrar al usuario, y el usuario puede ser capaz de subir o bajar el porcentaje o el valor tal cual como en una calculadora, y no encuentro como hacer para multiplicar un numero con miles por el porcentaje en javascript.

Comment: Hola, la verdad solo e visto tutoriales, pero no e avanzado nada, ya que no encuentro, ningun video donde enseñen a  multiplicar (con miles) en javascript.

Gracia por el apunte me pondre a leer soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, que bueno que estés iniciando en la programación y JavaScript es un buen comienzo. Cuando dices "multiplicar un numero con miles" a qué te refieres? Es decir en JS puedes solo multiplicar un numero "x * y" y luego dividirlo en 100

Comment: Hola, @HugoQuiñónez, a lo que me quiero referir es que tengo que imprimir en pantalla la el número con miles, pero esto no lo e visto, posible mi idea es que yo pueda hacer la multilplicación  y a en pantalla se muestre 300.000  separado por el punto cada 3 cifras

Comment: hola @AlvaroMejia, bienvenido a [es.so] . porfavor si encontraste la solucion a tu problema, ponela como respuesta explicando como funciona, no edites la pregunta arreglando los errores

Comment: Hola @Federico, no es una respuesta es el codigo que empece a trabajar. 
para tenerlo de referencia, para que entiendan un poco mejor lo que quiero hacer

Comment: si no entendi mal queres que se separen los numeros con `,` cada 3 numeros, y ejecutando tu codigo parece funcionar, por eso digo

Comment: @Federico pero como ves en el primer input (el usuario al ingresar deberia tambien de separarse, cada 3 numero pero esto no lo he logrado, hacer, esto fue lo que entendí que debía hacer.  siento la confusión es que soy nuevo en esto pero tomare tu consejo, y aprendere a mejorar la preguntas

Comment: ah okay ahora entiendo, una pregunta, que hace la funcion `noPuntoComa`?

Comment: @Federico no, esa se me fue en el codigo,  es que desde ayer estoy tratandolo de hacer con algunos tutoriales, pero es una función que no va, 
la puedo borrar?

Comment: @Federico lo que trato de hacer, es como cuando uno abre la calculadora de windows  a la hora de vos poner el numero esta con comas, y  puedes hacer multiplicaciones, normales, pero el resultado se imprime con separadores-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acá te dejo una solución :

- Función `separar` --> usando `substr` tomamos los caracteres desde `i` y `n` osea desde donde empezar hasta donde terminar, en este caso empezamos en 0 contamos 3 caracteres y cortamos el texto. Usando el método `push()` lo agregamos al array vacío que creamos llamándolo `lista` la cual quedaría tipo: `["300", "000", "000"]` y retornamos el array.
- Creamos una función para el evento `keyup` que llame la función `separar` cada vez que se agrega un numero y que su resultado lo ate con `'` (ya que con la coma, siendo un `float` se confunde con el divisor entre enteros y decimales) y se lo ponemos como valor al input.
- Ya que esto interfiere con el calculo se tiene que retocar un poco mas la preparación para los cálculos. en este caso la variable `m1` a la cual vamos a dividir en los `'` y lo volvemos a atar con `join("")` te puse el `console.log` para que veas como funciona.

**USA LA PANTALLA COMPLETA PARA VISUALIZAR**

```js
function multiplicar(){
      m1 = document.getElementById("multiplicando").value;
      m2 = document.getElementById("multiplicador").value;
      /* -------------------------*/
      console.log(m1)
      m1 = m1.split("'");
      console.log(m1)
      m1 = m1.join("");
      console.log(m1)
      
      x1 = m1 * m2 / 100;
      
      /* -------------------------*/
      
   //   m3 = m2 * 0.01;
    //  x =  m3 *  parseFloat(m1) ;
   //   x1 = x-2380000;

      document.getElementById("resultado").value = x1.toLocaleString();
        

      }
      const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      }


      function Sumar() {
          var n1 =1;
          var n2 = document.getElementById('multiplicador').value;
           var suma = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2);
         document.getElementById("multiplicador").value = suma;
          multiplicar();
      }


         function resta() {
              var r1 = 1;
              var r2 = document.getElementById('multiplicador').value;
              var resta = parseInt(r2) - parseInt(r1);
              document.getElementById("multiplicador").value = resta;
             multiplicar();
         }
         
        /* ----------------*/
        var input = document.getElementById("multiplicando");
        var valor ;
        function separar(str, n){
          let lista = [];
          let len = str.length;
          str = str.split("").reverse().join("");
          
          for (i = 0; i < len; i += n){
             lista.push(str.substr(i,n).split("").reverse().join(""));
          }
          return lista.reverse()
        }

        input.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
          valor = input.value;
          console.log(separar(valor.replace(/\'/gm, ""), 3).join("'"));
          input.value = separar(valor.replace(/\'/gm, ""), 3).join("'");
        })
```

```html
<form id="multiplicar">
      <div class="container-block">
  
      <div class="container-input">
        <label>$</label>   <input type="text" name="multiplicando" id="multiplicando"   value="300'000'000" onChange="multiplicar();"   placeholder="Escribe el valor">
      </div>
     </div>
 

      <div class="container-block">
           
            <div class="accion">
              <input type="button" onclick="resta();" value="-" class="resta">
                        <div class="container-input">
                          <input type="text" name="multiplicador" id="multiplicador" value="3" onChange="multiplicar();" onkeyUp="multiplicar();"   min="0" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                          <label style="    right: 130px;">%</label>
                        </div>
                 <input type="button" onclick="Sumar();" value="+" class="suma">
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-block-resultado">
    
            <div class="container-input">
                <label>$</label>   <input type="text" id="resultado">
              </div>
                </div>

    </form>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda y la explicación sea clara

**EDIT**
lo que te agregue fue :

- en la función `separar` di vuelta el la cadena utilizando el siguiente metodo : `split("")` converti la cadena en un array de caracteres unicos ej: `["3","0","0",...]` use el metodo `reverse()` para dar vuelta el contenido del array : `[...,"0","0","3"]` y lo volvi a unir con `join("")`. esto para que se empieze contando desde el fondo y no desde el primer numero de la cifra.

  - y hice lo mismo al momento de guardar los valores de 3 en 3 en la lista y por ultimo, `.reverse()` a la lista antes de que sea retornada, asi ponemos los numeros en orden nuevamente.

Comment: ahi edite los errores que tenia, perdon

Comment: gracias, ya vi que todo esta bien, me podes aclarar algo, si por ejemplo el usario  quiere hacer la multiplicación con un numero como 70.000.000 esto seria posible?, o tocaría hacer otra función?

Comment: en que sentido ? ahi puede poner el porcentaje que quiera, y el numero que quiera no tiene limitaciones ☺

Comment: hablo del primer input si por ejemplo pones setenta millones te formate cada 3 numeros, osea quiero que ese se pueda mostrar 70'000'000--> así me entiendes?

Comment: okay ahi modifico

Comment: @Gracias si me podes comentar el cambio que haces seria genial, para yo entender un poco mejor.

Comment: si me entendiste?

Comment: echo ☺, espero que te sea claro, exitos

Comment: Mucas gracias @Federico como te puedo encontrar para seguirte?

Comment: como puedo hacer para validar el input para que no pase de 1 el multiplicador?

Comment: como vas? :( me podes colaborar?

Answer (score 0):

puedes operar de la siguiente forma:

```
var cifra = 300000000;
var porcentaje = 3;
var resultado = 300000000 * porcentaje / 100;

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = cifra + " * " + porcentaje + "% = " + resultado;
```

Un saludo.

Buenas, edito la respuesta en función de tu ultimo comentario , si lo que quieres es formatear el numero lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
var cifra = 300000000;

cifra = cifra.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,'$1.');
cifra = cifra.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'');
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, pero a la hora de  mostrarlo como podría hacer para que se muestre separado por un punto cada 3 cifras.

Gracias

Comment: He modificado la solucion , con lo que sea me dices.